# Python guessing game hints and points systems

Tags: python

I'm writing my first python game and trying to incorporate two extra elements but I'm unsure how to write it.

1: The idea is that the game will generate a random three digit number with the inbuilt random module (ie. 123) and the user will have 23 tries to guess the correct numbers. It will initiate by asking the user to input three digits between 0-9. I want to create a hint system so that the user knows if they are on the right track. See the example in the link below (I can't embed images apparently).

[Click to see example Input/Output for hints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXn5u.jpg)

- A "W" indicates that all of the characters in the guess are wrong.
- One or more "X"s indicates that they have a correct character, but in an incorrect position
- One or more "R"s indicates they have a correct character in the right position

To get this kind of hint will I need to create 3 separate numbers and combine them together to form the target number or will I still be able to do it with the following code:

```
target = random.randint(111, 999)
```

I've started writing a function that takes in the variables guess (this is what the user has entered) and target (the generated number):

```
def get_hint(guess, target):
```

This is as far as I have gotten with it. Laughable, I know. I literally have no idea if it even possible to create this hint system.

2: I would also like it to have a points system where the points start at 10000 (if the user guesses correctly first try) and decreases by 10% each incorrect guess (second guess = 9000, third guess = 8100, etc.) to two decimal places. I have it incrementing a count for the amount of guesses the user has tried so when they guess the correct number the following happens:

```
if guess == target:
    print("Congratulations!")
    print("{} was the correct answer!".format(target))
    print("You guessed the correct answer in {} tries and scored {} points.".format(tries, points))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the point system is fairly trivial: just have a score varible and modify it at each round `score=score*0.9` and round it to 2 decimals when printing with `"{:.2f}".format(score)`

**Regarding the hint system :**

Having a list of three numbers will be far easier to deal with so I'll assume `target` and `guess` have one of the following format `"123"` or `[1,2,3]` (as strings can be indexed as lists)

The tricky part is doing the right comparisons because you have take care of what digit have already been matched against the target in order to give only `"r"` in the example case of guess=113 and target=333. Here is a function that does the job:

```
def hint(guess,target):

    if guess == target:
        print("win")
    else:
        #we store a list to keep track of the numbers 
        #already matched so we don't count them twice as x and r
        r=[0]*len(target) 

        #first we check if there's a direct match
        for i,n in enumerate(guess):
            if guess[i] == target[i]:
                r[i]=1

        #we make new lists without the digits that matched
        stripped_guess=[n for i,n in enumerate(guess) if r[i] == 0]  
        stripped_target=[n for i,n in enumerate(target) if r[i] == 0]  

        #we will now try to count the amount of x
        x=0
        for n in set(stripped_guess):
            #we count how many time that given digit appears 
            # in the two lists, the smallest is our x amount
            x+=min(stripped_guess.count(n),stripped_target.count(n))

        if sum(r) == 0 and x == 0:
            print("w")
        else:
            print("r"*sum(r)+"x"*x)
```

Some tests:

```
>>> hint(guess="404",target="404")
win
>>> hint("135","331")
rx
>>>hint("11123","12133")
rrrx
```

Comment: What about the "w" option for the guessing meaning they didn't get any digits correct?

Comment: And for the points system, how does that code work if is meant to decrease the 10000 by 10% each time they have an incorrect guess?

Comment: I corrected the score to decrease by 10% (and not 90% as it were) and added the `"w"` case with a small test at the end

Comment: Thank you! Just another question quickly, how would I get the values in 'hint' to return a value that can be used in another function?

Comment: Just use the return statement instead of all the `print` calls. `return` statements are a **very basic thing** in python, you won't be able to do anything without it. I stongly recommand that you find a book or a website to learn the bases of python.

Comment: I tried using the return statement but I couldn't use the value elsewhere. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39389409/python-code-error-guessing-game

Answer (score -1):

If you have a three-digit number in variable num, you can peel away the digits:
In [1]: num = 347

In [2]: num % 10

Out[2]: 7

In [3]: (num % 100) // 10

Out[3]: 4

In [4]: (num % 1000) // 100

Out[4]: 3

Then you can compare digits and place your Xs and Rs.

Comment: Not exactly, it will be like - Please enter a guess: 123,

Your guess, 123, was incorrect,
Your current hint is: XX

Comment: Which would mean 2 of the digits are correct

Comment: Does it make sense?